# Can an independent sentence stand alone if the subject is implied

Tags: sentence

I came across this sentence today:

> Consider, for example, William Carlos Williams, who worked as a physician for over forty years.

I understand that the "for example" part of this sentence is nonessential, and the "who worked as a physician for over forty years" is a nonessential relative clause. Because they both are nonessential, you should be able to take them out. This leaves you with "Consider William Carlos Williams". Is this a sentence (independent clause)? If it is, is it because the "you "is implied? Is it because of something else? Let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Commands have an implied "you" as a subject.](https://www.thoughtco.com/you-understood-grammar-1692618)

> In English grammar, "you" understood is the implied subject in most
>   imperative sentences

Comment: Does that mean that in "Let's dance!" the subject is also "you"?

Comment: Yes.  It means "[You] let us dance."  (Since "we" can't dance if you refuse.)